# Flutter Flash Chat application - Firebase problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

when iam tryin to run the app after adding the following dependencies i got this issues - by the way iam studding anjela flutter course

dependencies:
firebase_core: ^1.2.0
firebase_auth: ^1.2.0
cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0

[image]

Comment: it's not an error, it's a warning that indicates that the plugin is using deprecated APIs. It is not an issue that would block your development or learning.

Comment: As the @TirthPatel said, this isn't an error that would block your installation, it is just a warning that comes from the native implementation of the mentioned libraries. This can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings can be safely ignored. It just indicates that the packages use deprecated APIs.